# Unable to get the points to appear on D3 scatterplot

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Edit:  Added code to load callback according to comment.  Still get only single point though!!

I have the following D3 code, but I always get a blank graph, with just the scales appearing with a single (or many piled on top of each other) points (crosses).

The csv import seems to go OK as can be soon from the following output from mydata

```
Object { rating: 89, winsNoms: 80 }
Object { rating: 63, winsNoms: 30 }
Object { rating: 83, winsNoms: 30 }
```

and the dataset:

```
Id,Title,Year,Runtime,Country,imdbRating,imdbVotes,Budget,Gross,WinsNoms,IsGoodRating
13,Alone in the Dark,2005,96,"Canada, Germany, USA",2.3,37613,20000000,8178569,9,0
38,Boogeyman,2005,89,"USA, New Zealand, Germany",4.1,25931,20000000,67192859,0,0
52,Constantine,2005,121,"USA, Germany",6.9,236091,75000000,221594911,11,1
62,Diary of a Mad Black Woman,2005,116,USA,5.6,10462,5500000,50458356,26,0
```

I am not 100% sure about my scales, but I have examined many docs and can't see anything wrong.

The big change to things I have done before is to try to add a cross, with all of the transform/translate stuff.

I know all the scales are a bit wrong and my margins are probably off, but why I am I not seeing any spread of points?

```js
var margin = {top: 20, right: 19, bottom: 29, left: 39};
var w = 899;
var h = 449;

var mydata = [];

var x = d3.scale
          .linear()
          .range([-1, w]);

var y = d3.scale
          .linear()
          .range([h, -1]);

var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


// Grab the data
d3.csv('./movies.csv', function(error, csv){
    if (error) {
        console.log("Error thrown");
        throw error;
    }

    csv.forEach(function(d){
        mydata.push({rating: parseInt(d.imdbRating * 10),
                     winsNoms: parseInt(d.WinsNoms * 10)
        });
    });

    var x = d3.scale
      .linear()
      .range([-1, w]);
var y = d3.scale
  .linear()
  .range([h, -1]);


// Create some scales
x.domain([mydata, d3.max(0, function(d) {
  return d.rating;
})]);

//d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.x; }));
y.domain([mydata, d3.max(0, function(d) {
  return d.winsNoms;
})]);

// Stick the x axis in...
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(-1," + h + ")")
  .call(d3.svg
    .axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom"));

// and the y axis.
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(d3.svg
    .axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left"));

svg.append("g")
  .append("text")
  .attr("class", "titleText")
  .attr("y", margin.top)
  .attr("x", w / 2 + margin.left)
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text(" Wins+Nominations vs. IMDb Rating");


// Put the crosses in to place (i.e. the points)
svg.selectAll(".point")
  .data(mydata)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("class", "point")
  .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("cross"))
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    console.log(d);
    return "translate(" + x(d.rating) + "," + y(d.winsNoms) + ")";
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.point {
  fill: blue;
  stroke: #000;
}

.titleText {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" defer></script>
  <script src="myscript.js" defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what is a sample of your data set?

Comment: you need to do all the drawing in your load callback, the way you create your scales is wrong, look at any example on blocks

Comment: Thanks.  That helps.  Scale now draws correctly.  Still got all the point at the top of the y-axis though

Comment: once again your scales are wrong, read the docs and see examples on blocks (line chart)

Answer (score 0):

Answer was provided by https://stackoverflow.com/users/9938317/riov8

I needed to include most of my code in the callback function when loading the csv.  i.e. after I did this:

```
d3.csv('./movies.csv', function(error, csv){

if (error) {
    console.log("Error thrown");
    throw error;
}

csv.forEach(function(d){
    mydata.push({rating: parseInt(d.imdbRating * 10),
                 winsNoms: parseInt(d.WinsNoms * 10)
    });
});
```

Instead of closing it with a 
    });

I moved the brackets to the end of the code so that they encompoassed everything thing.

Thanks riov8